# Pass object reference into different class object array using public function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, polymorphism

Given class A and Class B. I need to use the "add" function as shown in the cpp file to store an object reference of class B in an object array of class A.

I should be able to use "->" as shown in the cpp file to call Class B's "print" function.

**Compile Time Error: void* is not a pointer-to-object type**

So how do I solve this error?

==================================================================================

// header file

```
// ABC.h

class A{
     private:
        size_t size_;
        void * a_[256];
        static int index_;
    public:
        void add(void * obj);
        void * operator[](int x){
            return a_[x];
        }


};

class B {
    private:
        const char * f_;
        const char * l_;

    public:
        B(const char * fn, const char * loc ):f_(fn), l_(loc){ A(); };
        void print();
};
```

// cpp file

```
#include "ABC.h"

int A::index_ = 0;

inline void A::add(void* obj){

    void * insertionPoint = static_cast<char *>(a_[index_]) + ( size_ * index_ );

    memcpy( insertionPoint, obj,  size_);

    ++index_;

}

inline void B::print(){
    ...
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    B b( "Name", "Some string");

    a.add( &b );

    a[0]->print(); // <-- This should be an object reference to B, but it is producing the error.

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Name Some string

Comment: What do you mean you *have everything working*? The code above is completely broken. Where's the implementation for `A::print`? The `print` functions in `B` and `C` do not override that in `A`. Also, `A` doesn't implement `operator[]`. Finally, what do you expect to happen here ... `*this = dynamic_cast<void*>(obj);`? I'm also curious to know what part of the standard library you're choosing to shun, and for what reason.

Comment: I think the code in main is an example of what he wants to be able to do. Because he says that everything is working except storing the reference of class objects b and c. @Praetorian is right though, the assignment to \*this is pretty suspect.

Comment: @Praetorian Could you please explain what I could do with A if A DID implement operator[]?

Comment: If you implemented `A::operator[]`, the statement `a[0]->print();` would make sense. You seem to have some misconceptions about inheritance also. It is not necessary to have `B` derive from `A` if all you want if for `A` to act as container for instances of `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution involved advice from all above comments**

Compare the differences between the question and answer to see the solution, fully.

What I needed to do was change class A's private a_ member to type A: A * _a[256]
NEXT: I needed to change the operator[] and the add method's parameter to type A, as well: A * operator[](A * obj)
NEXT: I needed to add a virtual void print()for inheritance purposes to class A.
FINALLY: Class B needed to inherit class A

**Below is working code**

NOTE: I am not sure if this code is entirely secure or deals with memory issues properly, but I do know that it prints to output what it was intended to print.

==================================================================================

// header file

```
// ABC.h

class A{
     private:
        size_t size_;
        A * a_[256];
        static int index_;
    public:
        void add(A * obj);
        A * operator[](int x); // Any subclass object reference of A can be assigned now. 
        virtual void print()const; // Virtual tells the compiler to look for other void print methods first.


};

class B : public A{
    private:
        const char * f_;
        const char * l_;

    public:
        B(const char * fn, const char * loc ):f_(fn), l_(loc){ A(); };
        void print()const;
};
```

// cpp file

```
#include "ABC.h"

int A::index_ = 0; // Need to call this here because it is declared static in Class A and can be used dynamically. 

inline A * A::operator[](int x){
    return a_[x]; // Implements operator[], so class A can act like a container.
}

inline void A::add(A* obj){

    a_[index_] = obj; // Adds a base or subclass object reference to class A object array.

    ++index_; // Need this to remember current index of object reference A's array.

}

inline void A::print()const{}

inline void B::print()const{

    std::cout <<  "B " << firstname_ << " works in " << location_ << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    A a;

    B b( "Name", "Some string");

    a.add( &b );

    a[0]->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Name Some string

Answer (score 0):

The following method makes no sense:

```
virtual void add(A * obj){
    *this = dynamic_cast<void*>(obj);
}
```

in case you want to store pointers to other instances of `A` within `A`, create an array of pointers where you will hold them, trying to "replace" the current instance (i.e. `*this =`...) makes no sense.

Also note that `dynamic_cast` would make sense if you want to examine whether `A*` points to instance of `B`:

```
A* a = new B();
// in compile time it's A*, but does it really point to instance of B? :
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

---

Why don't you start with something simpler? Let's say:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "a"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void print() /* const */ { std::cout << "b"; }
};
```

used as:

```
A* a = new A();
A* b = new B();
a->print();
b->print();
```

which (as it stands) outputs `ab`. Then you can change the `B`'s `print()` to `const` and realize that the `const`ness of method actually matters.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That was simply my attempt to try anything to get it to work. I have modified my question to be more specific. Sorry about that.